# Using Regex to grab multiple values from a string and drop them into an array?

Tags: ruby, regex, watir

Trying to grab the two $ values and the X value from this string in Ruby/watir:

> 16.67%: $xxx.xx down, includes the Policy Fee, and x installments of $xxx.xx

So far I've got:

```
16.67%:\s+\$(\d+.\d{2})
```

which grabs the first xxx.xx fine, what do I need to add to it to grab the last two variables and load this all into an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following, but regex may be unnecessary if the surrounding text is always the same:

```
\$(\d+.\d{2}).*?(\d+) installments.*?\$(\d+.\d{2})
```

http://www.rubular.com/r/sk5wO3fyZF

Comment: myarray = "16.67%: $xxx.xx down, includes the Policy Fee, and x installments of $xxx.xx".scan /\$\d+\.\d{2}/

Answer (score 0):

if you know that the text in between will always be the same you could just:

```
16.67%:\s+\$(\d+.\d{2}) down, includes the Policy Fee, and x installments of (\d+.\d{2})
```

Answer (score 0):

You better use scan.

```
sub(/.*%/, '').scan(/\$?([\d\.]+)/)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered just splitting the string on the $ character?, then manipulating what you get with a regex or basic string commands?

Comment: Well I dont just need the two $ I need the number X before installments as well..

Answer (score 0):

/\$(\d+.\d{2}).+\$(\d+.\d{2})/  should do it. it wont matter what text is there, only that there are two "$" in the sentence.